# jQuery sort list items on class name

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have a list that I need to sort depending on the class name.

The active one's should be on top, the one's without a class should be in the middle and the sm classes should be at the bottom.

Also the list should de on alfabetical order.

What is the best wat to get this result?

```
<ul class="options without-border expandable2">
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filteroption" value="Acer" name="merk"> ACER</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filteroption" value="Alcatel" name="merk"> ALCATEL</label>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filteroption" value="Apple" name="merk"> APPLE</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filteroption" value="Blackberry" name="merk"> BLACKBERRY</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filteroption" value="HTC" name="merk"> HTC</label>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filteroption" value="Huawei" name="merk"> HUAWEI</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filteroption" value="LG" name="merk"> LG</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filteroption" value="Nokia" name="merk"> NOKIA</label>
    </li>
    <li style="display: none;">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filteroption" value="Samsung" name="merk"> SAMSUNG</label>
    </li>
    <li style="display: none;">
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filteroption" value="Sony" name="merk"> SONY</label>
    </li>
    <li class="sm sm-show" style="display: block;"><a class="showmore" href="#">Alles bekijken</a></li>
    <li class="sm sm-hide" style="display: none;"><a class="showmore" href="#">minder</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem that you actually need to move `.sm` elements around - they will always stay in the same place if you choose the correct approach to modify the list:

```
$('.options').prepend(function() {
  var elements = [].slice.call(this.querySelectorAll('li:not(.sm)'), 0);
  elements.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.className.indexOf('active') === -1) - (b.className.indexOf('active') === -1)
      || a.querySelector('input').value.localeCompare(b.querySelector('input').value)
  });
  return elements;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z4Lze3sa/). Note that [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method moves elements in DOM (instead of recreating their copies).

Comment: You sir, YOU ARE AWESOME

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.options').each(function () {
    $('.active', this).prependTo(this);
    $('.sm', this).appendTo(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you wanted the .sm items handled but this gets the bulk of your sorting done.

```
var $options = $('.options'),
    items = $options.find('li').get();

items.sort(function(first, second) {
    var $first = $(first),
        $second = $(second);
    if ($first.hasClass('active') && !$second.hasClass('active')) {
        // Filter .active above everything
        return -1;
    } else if($first.hasClass('sm') && !$second.hasClass('sm')) {
        // Filter sm below everything
        return 1;
    }
    // At this point we know that they have the same class so compare the text
    return $first.find('label').text() < $second.find('label').text() ? -1 : 1;
});

// Reorder the dom
$options.html(items);
```