# Adding a sort function to order by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a sort function to work with the following code.

The code below filters through a list of items and groups by class name.

However, I wand to sort the order by the class of the parent ul

like so:-

```
<ul class="parent-section-a">
  <li class="section-a">item One</li>
  <li class="section-a">item Two</li>
  <li class="section-a">item Three</li>
  <li class="section-a">item Four</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent-section-b">
  <li class="section-b">item One</li>
  <li class="section-b">item Two</li>
  <li class="section-b">item Three</li>
  <li class="section-b">item Four</li>
</ul>
<ul class="parent-section-c">
  <li class="section-c">item One</li>
  <li class="section-c">item Two</li>
  <li class="section-c">item Three</li>
  <li class="section-c">item Four</li>
</ul>
```

The code i have so far is:-

```
// Get all the classes
var classes = $('[class^=section]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('class');
});

// Filter only unique ones
var uniqueClasses = $.unique(classes);

// Now group them
$(uniqueClasses).each(function(i, v)
{
    $('.'+v).wrapAll('<ul class ="parent-'+v+'"></ul>');
});
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Mark

Comment: can you provide what the result would be?

Comment: You just need to write a `sort()` handler function which compares the classes of the elements. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for an example of this. If you can give a much clearer example of the input HTML we may be able to help you more effectively.

Comment: The top html code is the result I am looking for, the javascript code is what I have to create the html example

Comment: the html input is a mixed list of li elements with classes associated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the order by the class of ul, this should be helping:
[jQuery sort list items on class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439572/jquery-sort-list-items-on-class-name)

Comment: Hi @Hesham AbuSaif, I have tried to apply this to my script but the sort function doesn't seem to do what I want it to http://jsfiddle.net/blackrainstudio/j0uqzvm9/4/ any suggestions?